# SSRS 2219 showing message "You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to obtain the necessary permissions."

Tags: reporting-services

I have newly configured SSRS 2019 and when I log in to the web portl.im getting this message and I can not perform anything in the portal. I have used my windows domain account to install SSRS and I have no idea since I should be the administrator.

SSRS message

[image: 1]

unknown message appear .I was expecting to log in to the portal and use the SSRS.

Comment: Was this installed on your local machine of on a server? Either way you will have to login using a local admin account on the machine that is running the SSRS service. From there you will be able to open the web portal home page and assign permissions to your account(s)

Comment: yes @AlanSchofield this is in a local machine . I have used a domain account.I change service account to the same domain user and restart.Now it is working.Thank for your advice.